# Sending Headers with Axis (HTTP headers) - not SOAP headers

Tags: java, soap, axis, soapui

im using a generated axis client to consume a service that requires headers
when using SOAPUI, i add the headers and the request looks like this

> POST `https://fttoo/service/v3.2/SOAP HTTP/1.1`
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>   Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
>   SOAPAction: ""
>   **Authorization: Bearer 123**
>   Content-Length: 270
>   Host: my host
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

when trying to set the headers with code i'm doing the following

```
proxy = (SessionServiceImplServiceSoapBindingStub)locator.getSessionService();
proxy._setProperty("Authorization", "Bearer 123");
```

this is not working well and i get Error 401, when inspecting the proxy object i see that a property called cachedProperties has the value of {Authorization=Bearer 123}

I've also tried proxy._setProperty(HTTPConstants.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer 123");
and also inside the stub, in the _call object....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given the fact that axis 1 is very old i generated a new web client using CXF instead of Axis, this way i was able to use cxf api to place the headers